# Full ingredients not appearing in the front end of the website - Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-backend

I have added ingredients in the backend in Full Ingredients but for particular brands it's not showing the in the PDP of the website. How can I get it appear?

However, for all the other brands it's showing in the website.

Comment: Please add your code or an image due to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are more details required to be able to fully answer your question. But I'm making an assumption that "Full Ingredients" is a custom product attribute that you have created in the Magento backend.

If that is the case, please make sure to toggle "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" to "Yes" when editing your customer attribute under Stores > Attributes > Product in the Magento admin.

Once you have selected the attribute you wish to make this change for, go to the "Storefront Properties" tab on the left and you will find the option in the screenshot below. Toggle this to "Yes", Save and then you may need to reindex and clear cache.

[Click here for Screenshot of the setting in Magento Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbhTv.jpg)